# 'HAVING' Clause. How do I get rid of the number? AdventureWorks2017/2019

Tags: sql, having, adventureworks

```
SELECT SUM(SubTotal)/17 AS AverageSales
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
WHERE SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL
```

-- 4734570.8343

That query gave me the result for the average amount of sales for each salesperson.

```
 SELECT SalesPersonID
 , SUM(SubTotal) AS TotalSalesBySalesPerson
 , FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS [Sales Person]
 FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
 JOIN Person.Person
 ON SalesOrderHeader.SalesPersonID = Person.BusinessEntityID
 WHERE SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY SalesPersonID, FirstName, LastName
 HAVING SUM(SubTotal) < 4734570
 ORDER BY TotalSalesBySalesPerson DESC
```

This query gives me the exact results I'm looking for but I want to replace the '4734570' value with an actual statement.
My guess was 'HAVING SUM(SubTotal) < SUM(SubTotal)/17' but that doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone help with this?

```
SELECT SalesPersonID
 , SUM(SubTotal) AS TotalSalesBySalesPerson
 , FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS [Sales Person]
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
JOIN Person.Person
ON SalesOrderHeader.SalesPersonID = Person.BusinessEntityID
WHERE SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY SalesPersonID, FirstName, LastName
HAVING SUM(SubTotal) < SUM(SubTotal)/17
ORDER BY TotalSalesBySalesPerson DESC
```

This is what I tried. It returned an empty table.

Answer (score 1):

If you queries are correct, you can just replace the value with a subquery to get the result:

```sql
SELECT salespersonid,
       Sum(subtotal)              AS TotalSalesBySalesPerson,
       firstname + ' ' + lastname AS [Sales Person]
FROM   sales.salesorderheader
       JOIN person.person
         ON salesorderheader.salespersonid = person.businessentityid
WHERE  salespersonid IS NOT NULL
GROUP  BY salespersonid,
          firstname,
          lastname
HAVING Sum(subtotal) < (SELECT Sum(subtotal) / 17 AS AverageSales
                        FROM   sales.salesorderheader
                        WHERE  salespersonid IS NOT NULL)
ORDER  BY totalsalesbysalesperson DESC
```

Also, you mentioned you were calculating an average... there is an `AVG()` function you may want to use instead of `SUM()/17`, but since I don't know your business rules I will leave it to you to explore.

Comment: I guess AVG() would be the way to go here, like Bjorg P mentioned. Otherwise if the amount of sales persons changes, your result is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

I think a cte (common table expression) would be your friend here.

Please notice the semicolon at the beginning of this ***untested*** statement:

```
; WITH summarizedData /*a temporary name for our summarized data*/ AS
(
   SELECT
      SUM(SubTotal)/17 AS AverageSales
   FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
   WHERE
      SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
   SalesPersonID
   , SUM(SubTotal) AS TotalSalesBySalesPerson
   , FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS [Sales Person]
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
INNER JOIN Person.Person
   ON SalesOrderHeader.SalesPersonID = Person.BusinessEntityID
, summarizedData -- Include our summarized data here
WHERE SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
   SalesPersonID,
   FirstName,
   LastName
HAVING
   SUM(SubTotal) < summarizedData.AverageSales
ORDER BY
   TotalSalesBySalesPerson DESC
```

Of course, if you really do need the average and not that literal 17, then the query is easier.

```
SELECT
   SalesPersonID
   , SUM(SubTotal) AS TotalSalesBySalesPerson
   , FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS [Sales Person]
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
INNER JOIN Person.Person
   ON SalesOrderHeader.SalesPersonID = Person.BusinessEntityID
WHERE SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
   SalesPersonID,
   FirstName,
   LastName
HAVING
   SUM(SubTotal) < AVG(SubTotal)
ORDER BY
   TotalSalesBySalesPerson DESC
```